# A minimization which works but not too much

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Here under is a method to calculate Dean's apportionment method

```
dean[v_, s_] := Module[{vv = v, ss = s}, ww = DeleteCases[vv, 0];
  var = Table[x[i], {i, Length[ww]}];
  obj = Total[
    Table[Log[(x[i]!)^3 Rationalize[2^(
         x[i] - 1)]/(x[i]^2 ww[[i]]^(x[i] - 1) ((2 x[i] - 1)!))], {i, 
      Length[ww]}]];
  const = Total[Table[x[i], {i, Length[ww]}]];
  cons1 = 
   ToExpression[
    StringReplace[
     ToString[Table[x[i] >= 0, {i, Length[ww]}]], {"{" -> "", 
      "}" -> "", "," -> " &&"}]];
  int = ToExpression[
    StringReplace[
     ToString[
      Table[x[i] ∈ Integers, {i, Length[ww]}]], {"{" -> "", 
      "}" -> "", "," -> " &&"}]];
  argmin = ArgMin[{obj, const == ss && cons1 && int}, var];
  zer = Table[0, {i, 1, Length[vv] - Length[ww]}];
  fin = Join[argmin, zer];
  Fold[Insert[#1, 0, #2] &, DeleteCases[fin, 0], Position[vv, 0]]]
dean[{0, 40, 20, 12, 0}, 20]
```

It works nicely until s=20. But at s=21, it fails. It's the same thing if I increase the length of `v`. Of course, I have tried to change `ArgMin` to `NArgMin` and some methods  but it doesn't ameliorate the situation. Mathematica complains of a division by 0. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Cyrille, would you describe what your code does, and what the values of the variables mean in the function call? For instance, is the s=21 input reasonable for the method? Otherwise, this may be seen as a code dump and a request for debugging services.

Comment: with great pleasure MarcoB. I have found that the minimization of the objective function leads to the Dean apportionment method which is used in the problem to apportionate seat in some senate of the world. There are algorithms but with our data base, our real v, the Dean method does not converge. So I have tried this method. It works but unfortunately, if s becomes too high it fails which is strange.

Comment: and One solution would be to list all the combinations  and to evaluate the function for each combination Then take the minimum. I have tried this brute force solution but It takes, for me, a huge lot of time to program it and I fail. And this does not answer why Mathematica fails for my case. Sorry not to be too reactive but I am in a place where I am not connected directly to the internet.

Comment: I will add that in many cases the number of seats is largely greater than 21. It's not a demand for debugging. The code works I think there is some thing weird with the command  as it do what I ask for small settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not exactly understand why `ArgMin` fails, but I suspect a difficulty in optimizing over the integers only.

An alternative is to use free numerical optimization over the reals (i.e. `NArgMin`), then rounding this result both up and down to integer values, constructing all possible tuples of those integers, which is a much smaller search space, and selecting the tuple that best represents the ratios in the original population. This is what I do below. Note that I also rewrote the conditions in what seems to me a more natural way, and localized the variables inside a `Module`:

```
ClearAll[dean2]

dean2[populations_, seats_] := Module[
  {nonzeropops, vars, objective, constraintOnTotal, constraintOnSign, min, 
  viableoptions, best},

  nonzeropops = DeleteCases[populations, 0];

  vars = Array[x, Length[nonzeropops]];
  objective = Sum[
     Log[(x[i]!)^3 2^(x[i] - 1)/(x[i]^2 nonzeropops[[i]]^(x[i] - 1) ((2 x[i] - 1)!))],
     {i, Length[nonzeropops]}];
  constraintOnTotal = Total[vars] == seats;
  constraintOnSign = And @@ Thread[vars >= 0];
  min = NArgMin[{objective, constraintOnTotal && constraintOnSign}, vars];

  viableoptions = Select[
    Tuples@Transpose@Through[{Floor, Ceiling}[min]], 
    Total[#] == seats &];

  best = First@
    Nearest[(Ratios /@ viableoptions) -> viableoptions, Ratios[nonzeropops]];

  Fold[Insert[#1, 0, #2] &, best, Position[populations, 0]]
]
```

This works fine even for very large seat numbers:

```
dean2[{0, 40, 20, 12, 0}, 21]
(* Out: {0, 11, 6, 4, 0} in 0.073 s *)

dean2[{0, 40, 20, 12, 0}, 210]
(* Out: {0, 117, 58, 35, 0} in 0.1s *)

dean2[{0, 40, 20, 12, 0}, 21000]
(* Out: {0, 11667, 5833, 3500, 0} in 0.14 s *)
```

---

Perhaps more directly, one can implement the spirit of Dean's apportionment method by minimizing the differences in the ratios of the numbers of representatives apportioned to each population, and the ratios of the populations themselves:

```
ClearAll[deanAlt]
deanAlt[populations_?(VectorQ[#, (# >= 0 &)] &), seats_?(# > 0 &)] := 
 Module[{nonzeropops, vars, min, viableoptions, best},
  nonzeropops = DeleteCases[populations, 0];
  vars = Array[s, Length[nonzeropops]];
  min = ArgMin[{Norm[First@*Ratios /@ Partition[vars, 2, 1] - Ratios[nonzeropops]], Total[vars] == seats}, vars];
  viableoptions = Select[Tuples@Transpose@Through[{Floor, Ceiling}[min]], Total[#] == seats &];
  best = First@Nearest[(Ratios /@ viableoptions) -> viableoptions, Ratios[nonzeropops]];
  Fold[Insert[#1, 0, #2] &, best, Position[populations, 0]]
]
```

This reproduces the results from the original `dean`, and from `dean2` above, and it is much, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the constraint to "> 0" rather than ">= 0" it appears to work; however, I do not know if the results for larger values of `s` are reasonable since you did not provide the expected results.

```
dean[v_, s_] := Module[{vv = v},
  ww = DeleteCases[vv, 0];
  var = Array[x, Length[ww]];
  obj = Total[
    Table[Log[(x[i]!)^3 2^(x[i] - 
           1)/(x[i]^2 ww[[i]]^(x[i] - 1) ((2 x[i] - 1)!))], {i, 
      Length[ww]}]];
  const = Total[var];
  cons1 = And @@ Thread[var > 0];
  int = var ∈ Integers;
  argmin = ArgMin[{obj, const == s && cons1 && int}, var];
  zer = ConstantArray[0, Length[vv] - Length[ww]];
  fin = Flatten[{argmin, zer}];
  Fold[Insert[#1, 0, #2] &, DeleteCases[fin, 0], Position[vv, 0]]]

dean[{0, 40, 20, 12, 0}, #] & /@ {20, 21, 50, 100, 210}

(*  {{0, 11, 6, 3, 0}, {0, 11, 6, 4, 0}, {0, 28, 14, 8, 0}, {0, 55, 28, 
  17, 0}, {0, 117, 58, 35, 0}}  *)
```

Comment: Dear Bob Hanlon, I will read your answer and then I will give you my return. In all cases a full lot of thanks